# Saving values from a time select into a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I want to have a drop down time select that saves as a string but I keep getting the following exception: 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes. Here is the code that I have written:

```
<%= f.time_select :appointment_time, :minute_step => 5, :ignore_date => true %>
```

When I submit the form I get the following values in a params hash

```
"appointment_time(4i)"=>"12", "appointment_time(5i)"=>"00"
```

Is there any way to easily grab those two values and save the result as "12:00:00"?

Comment: Why save as a string instead of as a time attribute? I think if appointment_time is of type time, Rails handles converting the params.

Comment: I get the same error either way as a time or string and dealing with a string in this context is easier.

Comment: Huh, that's weird, I tried setting up a scaffolded resource like this: rails g resource user name location wake_up_time:time. The scaffolding automatically used time_select for wake_up_time in the form and it's saving the object fine. When I tried using time_select for location (which is a string attribute) it gave me the multiparameter error.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say you have it as a time field, that means if you look at the field in your schema.rb file, it looks like this: t.time "appointment_time". I'm certain that if the attribute is a time field in the database then ActiveRecord knows how to take the multiple parameters and parse them into a single time value.

Comment: No, it looks like this: t.string "appointment_time", and I want it to remain as a string. (there are separate design issues for this reasoning"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating different columns for each value of the time as strings, and then joining everything together after creation. This is not the most elegant solution, but it works for my application

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are more than just the appointment keys in the params hash:

```
params[:your_model].select {|k,v| k =~ /^appointment_time/ }.
  sort.map {|f| f.last.to_s }.join(':')
```

Of course, this also assumes that the appointment_time field in your table isn't a DateTime or Date field. You'd have to do this before updating the (assumed) ActiveRecord model instance's attributes. There are simpler ways to do this, but without seeing the code and backtrace it's tough to know whether they'd work.

**Edit**

```
processed = params.dup
processed[:your_model][:appointment_time] = params[:your_model].
  select {|k,v| k =~ /^appointment_time/ }.sort.map {|f| f.last.to_s}.join(':')
@model.update_params(processed[:your_model])
```

That's probably more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm... this didn't quite work for me, but I can show what is working if that helps. Currently I have this as a text field and if I type in a time like 08:00:00 this works perfectly but for the drop down methods I still get the assignment of multiparameter attributes. If you give me a few minutes I can re-write the field and give you a backtrace, and update the question.

Comment: The reason it isn't working is b/c the parameters like this "appointment_time(4i)"=>"12", "appointment_time(5i)"=>"00" are still hanging around in the params hash. If you delete them and then store the result of the above in params[:your_model][:appointment_time] it will work

Comment: @Adam is right. If you're just passing the params hash to something like update_attributes or save, Rails will still try to build and store the Time object. You have to actually assign the string as the value of the key in the hash.

Comment: Also, I believe that params is actually a method that returns the processed http parameters, so you'd probably be best off dup'ing it.